# Saving a table in .xls format to achieve an alternative to docmd.sendObject acSendTable

Tags: excel, vba, ms-access

I'm trying to find an alternative to the docmd.sendObject acSendTable to send an email with a .xls attached to it

```
DoCmd.SendObject acSendTable, "Employees", acFormatXLS,"Nancy Davolio; Andrew Fuller", "Joan Weber", "Current Spreadsheet of Employees", False
```

I'm trying to make it by using another function creating an outlook application an then passing the data and finally send it with .send

But my problem is that I don't know how to save the table in access in that xls format to a variable.

¿Could you help me please?

Comment: Check **[DoCmd.OutputTo](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/access.docmd.outputto)** This will allow you to transfer a table to an Excel File. Later on, you could code something to attach that file to an e-mail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Pᴇʜ I was able to solve my issue.

Just used doCmd.outputTo in a xls format to a path and then with a String variable with the name of the path\TheFile.xls i was able to send the email with the xls file.

Thank you.